# How to call a function every 5 minutes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I'm looking to call a function at 10am, 10.05am, 10.10am, 10.15am....

I tried using

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 5), (Timer t)  { function...})
```

But it doesn't call the function at 10am, 10.05am... If I were to start the timer at 10.02am, it will call the function at 10.07am, 10.12am. Any idea how to workaround this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround where i use a timer to trigger a periodic timer

Rough code as shown below:

```
 Timer(nextFiveMinInterval.difference(DateTime.now()),
              () { Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 5), (Timer t)  { function...})
})
```

Comment: You can go simply using modulus on minutes.

`if(DateTime.now().minute % 5 == 0){
   function();
}`